# Restrict Azure App Service to a whitelist of IPs without returning 403

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure App Service where the customer is using an Akamai WAF in front of it to connect to it. Now I have the requirement that the App Service should not be reachable other then through that WAF. I got a list of IPs I have entered in the App Service Networking in the Access Restrictions list (App Service -> Networking -> Access restrictions).

This works pretty well in principle, but if I now try to access the service directly (so by using appname.azurewebsites.net), not through the WAF, it will return a 403 error response. But the requirement is that the service should not answer, at all.

Is there a way to achieve that in Azure? What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: On a Windows WebApp, you could use web.config to restrict IP addresses. The response can be configured as per "denyAction". See: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/ip-and-domain-restrictions-for-windows-azure-web-sites/

Comment: But can I choose so that the service won't answer at all? Probably only choose between different 4xx errors, right?

Comment: I've seen this a lot and never understood why the 403 is bad and why not handshaking TCP is better. Your application never sees that request since the 403 is returned by the App Service frontends, so... why?

Comment: @evilSnobu because other people are involved who will not listen. That's why.

Comment: I feel you person our there, but you should insist and ask them https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuwBf.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, when you configure ip restrinctions on App Services, the App Service will return the 403 forbidden page from Azure.

So, if you want to Avoid default 403 when IP Restrinctions are configured on App Services, you could vote up this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/37183225-avoid-default-403-when-ip-restrinctions-are-config) to promote this to be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to achieve this behaviour right now in an app service:
What you need to do is use an app service plan on the Isolation tier, create a v-net and add a network security group to it where you can restrict inbound ips.

This is pretty expensive, but currently the only way.

What I ended up with is to use a VM with a v-net, as this is much cheaper. An App service on the isolation tier unfortunatly would have destroyed the budget.